# Flex AIR compile error access of undefined property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Working through a series of Adobe AIR examples I have encountered a compilation error with one of them that I have distilled into the following demo application file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication
  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.events.MenuEvent;

      private static const MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";

      private function onMenuItemClick(evt:MenuEvent):void
      {
        switch(evt.label)
        {
          case MENU_DEMO:
            break;
        }
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="5">
    <mx:MenuBar id="menuBar"
      width="100%"
      labelField="@label"
      itemClick="onMenuItemClick(event);">
      <mx:XMLList>
        <menuitem label="Error">
          <menuitem label="{MENU_DEMO}" />
        </menuitem>
      </mx:XMLList>
    </mx:MenuBar>
  </mx:VBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

for which the descriptor file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.0.M6">
  <id>ErrorDemo</id>
  <filename>ErrorDemo</filename>
  <name>Error Demo</name>
  <version>v0.1</version>
  <description>Demo undefined property error</description>
  <copyright></copyright>
  <initialWindow>
    <title>Error Demo</title>
    <content>ErrorDemo.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
  </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Compilation produces the following output

```
C:\Projects\AIR\ErrorDemo>amxmlc ErrorDemo.mxml
Loading configuration file C:\Projects\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\air-config.xml
C:\Projects\AIR\ErrorDemo\ErrorDemo.mxml(28):  Error: Access of undefined property _ErrorDemo_XMLList1.

          <menuitem label="{MENU_DEMO}" />
```

The problem seems to be down to the use of the static const {MENU_DEMO} bound to the menuitem tag's label attribute because substituting it with text leads to no compilation error. Adobe's Using Flex 4.6 documentation states that static constants can be used as data binding sources, but maybe not in the way they're used here. Does anyone know what the problem is with using them in this way?

To clarify: replacing the bound constant reference `{MENU_DEMO}` with the string literal `Demo...` produces the following expected output. But using a string literal in place of the bound constant reference defeats the purpose of using a bound constant. Which is what seems to generate the error, and is the point of this post.

[image: ErrorDemo expected output]

Comment: ANd just suggestion, please update your SDK to Apache Flex 4.16 with latest Adobe AIR, it has nice installer **http://flex.apache.org**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in what a Flex 4 version of the mxml code looks like, here is what I came up with, following @ProgrammerDancuk's suggestion, who really should receive credit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication
  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.events.MenuEvent;

      private static const MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";

      private function onMenuItemClick(evt:MenuEvent):void
      {
        switch(evt.label)
        {
          case MENU_DEMO:
            break;
        }
      }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <fx:XMLList id="demoMenu">
      <menuitem label="Error">
        <menuitem label="{MENU_DEMO}" />
      </menuitem>
    </fx:XMLList>
    </fx:Declarations>

  <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="5">
    <mx:MenuBar id="menuBar"
      width="100%"
      labelField="@label"
      itemClick="onMenuItemClick(event);">
      <mx:dataProvider>
        {demoMenu}
      </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:MenuBar>
  </mx:VBox>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding `[Bindable]` before `private static const MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";`
it becomes:

```
[Bindable]
private static const MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";
```

Comment: Adding `[Bindable]` produces an `Error: [Bindable] not allowed on const member variables.` response from the compiler, even after updating the SDK to Apache Flex 4.16.1

Comment: Have you convert your code to Flex 4? I mean using <s:WindowedApplication>

Comment: @minipc does it work if you **don't** make it a `const` and use a `var` instead? Try:  `private static var MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";`

Comment: @VC.One substituting `var` for `const`, with or without the `[Bindable]` qualifier makes no difference to the resulting error message.

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk obviously I am working from a text that is somewhat out-of-date compared to my installed development environment and unfortunately I have only a few days experience of Flex AIR coding. So far my efforts to convert the code to Flex 4 have only resulted in an avalanche of further errors. But thanks for your suggestion. I will keep at it.

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk Your Bindable suggestion didn't work. But your Flex 4 conversion suggestion (which I just figured out how to do, after a bit of trial and error) did work. So if you edit your answer to include that, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Flex but from some research about your problem I noticed...

**(1)**

Your code has:

```
<menuitem label="{MENU_DEMO}" />
```

Try setting that as:

```
<menuitem label text="{MENU_DEMO}" />
```

**(2)**

Also since you say `itemClick="onMenuItemClick(event);"` shouldn't that be backed up by:

```
import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;
```

**(3)**

What is the expected result if your code compiled correctly?

I can't (or won't) test any Flex code so let me know if this works or errors...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication
  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      import mx.events.MenuEvent;
      import mx.events.ItemClickEvent; //add this

      [Bindable]
      public var MENU_DEMO:String = "Demo...";

      public function onMenuItemClick(evt:MenuEvent):void //or try... (evt:MenuEvent = null):void
      {
        if (evt.label.text == MENU_DEMO) //untested
        {
          //do something here
          evt.label.text = "Changed...";
        }

      }

    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="5">
    <mx:MenuBar id="menuBar"
      width="100%"
      labelField="@label"
      itemClick="onMenuItemClick(event);">
      <mx:XMLList xmlns="">
        <menuitem label="Error" />
        <menuitem label text="{MENU_DEMO}" />
        </menuitem>
      </mx:XMLList>
    </mx:MenuBar>
  </mx:VBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: have updated original post to include expected output, and figured out how to convert the code to Flex 4, which turned out to be the solution.